# Sync'ing iOS contacts to application database (What to use as a identifier reference?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

how do I determine if the contact is the same contact since there is no identifier/primary key that I could use as a reference?

1. If I use the "Name" as a reference, there might be two names that is the same or the name might change.
2. If I use the "Name" + "mobile number" as the reference, then if the mobile number changes, then I will have two records for the same person.

What to do now?

Comment: C#? What are you using to build this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the AddressBook framework.

ABRecord has the `uniqueId` property you can use for this.

Comment: UniqueId if the iPhone is wipe and restored the uniqueId would then change?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I'm guessing it wouldn't change, as long as synced with the same computer, or a computer with the same Address Book contacts.